RPGLE File declaration
I need to write a program that reads a file from library 1 and writes it to another file in another library. The problem is that both files have the same name and format.
I've tried renaming the format, but the program still considers the two files to be identical and is unable to identify the second, which is in another library.
Have you any ideas pleause?
thank you very much for your help

Assuming a supported version of the OS..
You need to use EXTNAME/EXTDESC
dcl-f myfile1 extdesc('LIB1/MYFILE') extfile(*EXTDESC) rename(MYFILEA:FORMAT1);
dcl-f myfile2 extdesc('LIB2/MYFILE') extfile(*EXTDESC) rename(MYFILEA:FORMAT2);


Free format
dcl-f MYFILE usage(*input) extfile('MYLIB/MYFILE');

Fixed format
FMYFILE    IF   E           K DISK    extfile('MYLIB/MYFILE')

See the EXTFILE(filename | *EXTDESC)  keyword documentation.

When a file is declared, global variables are automatically created with names corresponding to the names of the fields in the file record.
If you declare two files with the same record formats, even using extfile('MYLIB/MYFILE') as stated above, there will still be a field name conflict.
You can avoid it in two ways - rename the fields and record formats
dcl-f Input  disc(*ext) 
             extfile(*extdesc) 
             extdesc('LIB1\MYFILE') 
             usage(*input) 
             rename(RECFMT:INPUTREC)
             prefix('I_');
dcl-f Output disc(*ext) 
             extfile(*extdesc) 
             extdesc('LIB2\MYFILE') 
             usage(*output) 
             rename(RECFMT:OUTPUTREC)
             prefix('O_');

and then all the fields of the first file will begin with I_ and the second with O_ and there will be no conflict in names.
The second way is to declare the files as qualified. In this case, global variables with field names will not be created
dcl-f Input  disc(*ext) 
             extfile(*extdesc) 
             extdesc('LIB1\MYFILE') 
             usage(*input) 
             qualified;
dcl-f Output disc(*ext) 
             extfile(*extdesc) 
             extdesc('LIB2\MYFILE') 
             usage(*output) 
             qualified;

In this case, to work with the file you will need to declare data structures
dcl-ds dsInput  likerec(Input.RECFMT:  *all);
dcl-ds dsOutput likerec(Output.RECFMT: *all);

(here and above RECFMT is the name of the recording format in your file).
And you will need to work with the file using these structures
read Input.RECFMT dsInput;
dsOutput = dsInput;
write Output.RECFMT dsOutput;


Hi thank you for your response, could you please provide me the equivalent in fixed format?

Alas, my experience with RPG is only 7 years and I immediately wrote for free. I can only read the fixed code (as they say “with a dictionary”), since sometimes I have to modify old modules, but I didn’t have to write anything on it.
